# How does XmlReader::next position the cursor when it returns false

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

If I have some XML, for example:

```
<library>
    <books>
        <book>
            <title>book #1</title>
        </book>
        <book>
            <title>book #2</title>
        </book>
    </books>
    <authors>
         <author>
             <name>author #1</name>
         </author>
         <author>
             <name>author #2</name>
         </author>
    </authors>
</library>
```

And having manoeuvred my cursor to the first book element I loop using:

```
do {
    //...
} while($xml->next("book"));
```

**When my cursor is on the last book element and the next("book") is called, what happens to the cursor?**

- Does it stay on the last book element and return false.
- Does it move to the `</library>` and return false.
- Does it do something else?

I cannot figure out how to get the current cursor position to figure this out for myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having looked at the source code of that function:
http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/xmlreader/php_xmlreader.c#821

It would appear that pointer moves to the end of the XML.

Answer (score 3):

`XMLReader::next()` moves to the next node by skipping all subtree nodes. That is, it goes to the next node that has the same or lower *`XMLReader::$depth`* as the current one. If there is no next elment-node (after the end of document), the reader stops going to the next node.

In your case you specify a local-name with the parameter, in such a case, it will not take all of those matching next nodes, but only those, that are an element-node with the local-name given in the parameter.

> When my cursor is on the last book element and the next("book") is called, what happens to the cursor?

```
  cursor is currently here
            |
            v
            <book>
                <title>book #2</title>
            </book>
        </books>
        <authors>
             <author>
                 <name>author #1</name>
             </author>
             <author>
                 <name>author #2</name>
             </author>
        </authors>
    </library>
```

From the current cursor position, `next('book')` would not find any other element-node with the local-name "`book`" in the document (skipping subtree nodes) before reaching the end of document. So it will be at the end of document. `XMLReader::$nodeType` is `XMLReader::NONE` then, and `XMLReader::$depth` is `0`.

So in your case, it moves to the end of the document.

> - Does it stay on the last book element and return false.

No, it does not stay. That is for two reasons: First, you called `next()` which commands to move on. So the cursor location is expected to change. Second, XMLReader does not keep much state. It only knows *current*. There is not something like *last* or *first*. There is only *current*. The node-type of *current* is `XMLReader::$nodeType`. If it is `XMLReader::NONE` you either just opened (beginning of file) or you consumed the whole document (end of file).

> - Does it move to the `</library>` and return false.

No, it does not move to `</library>`. That is because you used `next()` with the local-name parameter. It would have moved there without the parameter (just `$xml->next()` *multiple* times), however as that operation would have been successful, it would have returned `true` then.

> - Does it do something else?

Yes, it merely does what I wrote above and what is documented in the [`XMLReader::next()` PHP manual page](http://php.net/reader.next).

> I cannot figure out how to get the current cursor position to figure this out for myself.

As XMLReader only knows *current* there is not much of a cursor position maintained. XMLReader is forward-only on elements, there is only limited movement within the opening tag of an element, to read the attributes and then jumping "back" to the element.

For information about the *current* node, there is the `->nodeType` field, as well as the `->depth` field.

Additionally you can visualize the node at the cursor be `->expand()`ing it and import it into a `DOMDocument` to save it as XML. However in your case you're after the end of the document, so you can not expand any longer. Check with the `->nodeType` field first then.

I also have in my [XMLReaderIterator library on github](https://github.com/hakre/XMLReaderIterator) some dump function that can be useful to debug nodes and structure ([`XMLReaderNode::dump()`](https://github.com/hakre/XMLReaderIterator/blob/master/src/XMLReaderNode.php#L268)).

You also might find the iterators there useful in using XMLReader, for example there is one that iterates only over children and stops when done.